# Changing text color of specific column based on value of cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I am trying to select the `Pass_Fail` column in my datagridview and loop through all of the cells in it. If the cell contains "Pass" i will change the background color of the cell to green and if it contains "Fail" I will change the color to red. I am also using a binding source to retrieve the data to fill up the datagridview cells. I have been trying to figure this out all day and some help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
field 1    field 2     field3     Pass_Fail    field5
value1     value2      value3     Pass         value5
value1     value2      value8     Fail         value5
```

Comment: Use DataGridView.CellFormatting event.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.8 - `CellFormatting` event

Answer (score 1):

An example derived from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.8

This would be an example of how you could implement it for your situation using the CellFormatting event on your datagridview control:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.Equals("Pass_Fail"))
            {
                if (e.Value.Equals("Pass"))
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                else if (e.Value.Equals("Fail"))
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                else
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like i was approaching this problem the wrong way